Why won't instagrapi download and process reels into a Database
Been stuck on this for a few days now. Basically, everything was working fine, until one day it randomly stopped working when downloading reels.
I've added some debugging to help try pinpoint what's happening, as before I just had downloading times, and upload times.
By the looks of it so far, instagrapi can successfully connect and process accounts, including media, however it just doesn't want to download anything, which is strange.
I've double checked my DB, as well as instragrapi documentation and rate limiting from Instagram. I'm pretty sure everything is accurate and good.
Code is below, as well as what I recieve from Shell (with some blurred priv info)
from instagrapi import Client
from db import Session, Reel, ReelEncoder
import json
import config
import time
import auth
import helpers as Helper
import os

def get_reels(account, api):
    try:
        user_id = api.user_id_from_username(account)
        print(f"User ID for account {account}: {user_id}")
        medias = api.user_medias(user_id, config.FETCH_LIMIT)
        print(f"Fetched {len(medias)} media items for account {account}")
        reels = [item for item in medias if (item.product_type == 'clips' and item.media_type == 2)]
        print(f"Filtered {len(reels)} reels for account {account}")
        return reels
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching reels for account {account}: {e}")
        return []

def get_file_name_from_url(url):
    path = url.split('/')
    filename = path[-1]
    return filename.split('?')[0]

def get_file_path(file_name):
    return os.path.join(config.DOWNLOAD_DIR, file_name)

def main(api):
    Helper.load_all_config()
    session = Session()
    
    for account in config.ACCOUNTS:
        print(f"Processing account: {account}")
        reels_by_account = get_reels(account, api)

        for reel in reels_by_account:
            if reel.video_url:
                try:
                    print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
                    print(f"Processing Reel - Code: {reel.code}")
                    print(f"Video URL: {reel.video_url}")

                    # Check if the reel already exists in the database
                    exists = session.query(Reel).filter_by(code=reel.code).first()
                    if exists:
                        print(f"Reel with code {reel.code} already exists in the database.")
                        continue
                    
                    filename = get_file_name_from_url(reel.video_url)
                    filepath = get_file_path(filename)

                    print(f"Downloading Reel From: {account} | Code: {reel.code}")
                    print(f"Download Path: {filepath}")

                    # Attempt to download the reel
                    result = api.clip_download_by_url(reel.video_url, filename, config.DOWNLOAD_DIR)
                    print(f"Download Result: {result}")

                    # Verify if the file was downloaded
                    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
                        print(f"Failed to download the reel. File not found: {filepath}")
                        continue

                    print(f"Successfully downloaded Reel Code: {reel.code} | Path: {filepath}")

                    print('<---------Database Insert Start--------->')

                    # Add the reel to the database
                    reel_db = Reel(
                        post_id=reel.id,
                        code=reel.code,
                        account=account,
                        caption=reel.caption_text,
                        file_name=filename,
                        file_path=filepath,
                        data=json.dumps(reel, cls=ReelEncoder),
                        is_posted=False,
                    )
                    session.add(reel_db)
                    session.commit()

                    print('Inserted Record into Database')
                    print('<---------Database Insert End--------->')
                    
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error processing reel {reel.code}: {e}")
    
    session.close()


    # time.sleep(int(config.SCRAPER_INTERVAL_IN_MIN) * 60)
    # main(api)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        api = auth.login()
        print("Logged in successfully")
        main(api)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during script execution: {e}")


Image which shows shell output.
It would be great if someone could figure out what the hell is happening haha.
